# Performance of Azure VM vs Cloud Service

Tags: azure

I have the same website running in both an Azure VM (ARM) and a classic Cloud Service.  The Cloud Service is using a Standard D2 v2 instance.  The VM is running in a Standard DS3 v2 instance.  Running the exact same workload, the Cloud Service finishes in about half the time even though it only 2 cores vs 4 in the VM.

I connected to both servers using remote desktop.  Looking in task manager, they both show Xeon E5-2673 v3 CPUs running at 2.4 GHz.  The disk utilization is low (less than 100 KB/s).  I can see that the processor load has the same shape on both systems (2 threads maxed out for the first half of the run, dropping to 1 thread maxed out for the second half).

Does anyone have any ideas why the Cloud Service would be inherently faster than the VM?  Is there anything I can check or modify on the VM to get performance closer to the Cloud Service?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the workload?  Are you timing web page loads?  Is it a utility pulling and pushing data from different sources?  Something else entirely?

What's the disk layout of the VM (# of disks, size, and standard vs. premium)?

Comment: This is a CPU-intensive workload, calculating hourly cooling and heating loads along with associated HVAC equipment performance parameters.  There is very little IO, but it does allocate a large amount of memory (approx 1-1.5 GB).  Initially, I just had the default C: drive (128GB, Premium, with Read/Write caching). For grins, I also added a 1TB disk (Premium, Read only caching) and moved the web files there. It didn't make a difference.